# Regular expression to match any string within brackets *but without whitespace*

Tags: regex

If I have a string like so: `<Hello> < World>` I would like to match `Hello` but ignore `World` due to the whitespace.

So far I'm using this, `/\<(.*?)\>/g` but this returns both `Hello` and `World`. I would like to ignore any in-bracket words that contain any whitespace at all.

Comment: I posted an answer with PCRE (looks like you are trying to use it) with live demo @regex101

Comment: The `<` and `>` have no special meaning (in regex) so they don't need to be escaped. Where is this regex being used?

Comment: @chris85: it's true. Note that in the gnu POSIX flavour *(gnu grep or sed for example)* `\<` stands for a left word boundary and `\>` for a right word boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PCRE:

```
/<(\w+)>/g
```

[Check Live Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uJ3qV4/2)

Answer (score 0):

`\S` is the qualifier for non-whitespace character. Use this:

```
/\<(\S*?)\>/g
```